# XSD: reference namespace of wildcard with ##other namespace in the case of an extension

Tags: xsd

I have an XSD schema with target namespace "ns1" which defines the following type:

```
<xs:complexType name="type1">
  <xs:sequence>
    <any namespace="##other" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" processContents="lax"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Now another XSD schema with target namespace "ns2" uses this type like this:

```
<xs:complexType name="type2">
  <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:extension base="ns1:type1"/>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

`##other` is defined as "Any well-formed XML that is from a namespace other than the target namespace of the type being defined (unqualified elements are not allowed)" ([see](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#ref34)).

Will the `<any>` wildcard in "type2" (inherited from "type1") use "ns2" or "ns1" as excluded namespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ##other will always be in the context defined by schema ns1, i.e. ns1 is the excluded namespace.