# What does the "namespace='##other' processContents='lax'" mean?

Tags: wix

I read WiX documentation.

Time of time in the WiX documentation I see the phrase "*Any Attribute (namespace='##other' processContents='lax') Extensibility point in the WiX XML Schema. Schema extensions can register additional attributes at this point in the schema*". For example i see it [here](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/product.html).

I don't understand this phrase and in particular what is specified in the brackets. I will be grateful for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The referenced subphrase `namespace='##other' processContents='lax'` is XSD terminology; see questions on [##other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8834109/xsd-reference-namespace-of-wildcard-with-other-namespace-in-the-case-of-an-ex) and [processContents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27420156/processcontents-strict-vs-lax-vs-skip-for-xsdany) for more details on what they directly mean.

In this context, this allows you to insert qualified (i.e. namespaced) attributes into a WiX element and still validate the resulting XML document. Most WiX elements allow both attributes and child elements of this nature. They are used, as the text suggests, to allow for [extensions to WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/general/extension_usage_introduction.html) that process these attributes and elements as part of a build step. You can [create your own extensions](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixdev/extensions/extension_development_simple_example.html) to automate or simplify specialized tasks that the WiX team doesn't implement in core.